# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for Application

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am creating my first spring boot application using maven and i am getting this error:

> Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   Bank_Application:Bank_Application:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer
>   artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.2.RELEASE

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Bank_Application</groupId>
    <artifactId>Bank_Application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Firewall/Proxy/Not configured repositories issue...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a proxy issue, that's quite common. (especially in banks where security policies are often very strict). See the [guide to Configuring a proxy](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html), there are also a lot of questions on SO related to such issue.

If you don't know what your proxy configuration ought to be, discuss it with your IT services.